# How to convert pointclouds to mesh using pyntcloud library

Tags: python, mesh, point-clouds

I am learning how to use the pyntcloud library but have become stuck at converting point clouds to meshes. According to the online documentation a Delunay3D structure is available but I cannot figure out how to use it.

There is a "convex_hull" structure that can generate a mesh even though it does not show up in the docstring. I do not want an encapsulating mesh though.

```
from pyntcloud import PyntCloud

my_pointcloud = PyntCloud.from_file('my_pointcloud.ply')
mesh_id = my_pointcloud.add_structure('delaunay_3d')
```

There should be some version of 'delaunay_3d' keyword that activates the structure but I keep getting.

> ValueError: Unsupported structure. Check docstring

If someone knows the correct keyword or can point me to a list of working keywords it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

pyntcloud maintainer here. Sorry for the lack of documentation about some features.

The correct keyword is `delanuay3D`, which is defined in:
 [https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud/blob/master/pyntcloud/structures/**init**.py#L12](https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud/blob/master/pyntcloud/structures/__init__.py#L12)

I'm planning to add more complex 3D reconstruction methods, in particular the poisson surface reconstruction.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, `delanuay3D_id = new_cloud.add_structure("delanuay3D")`. According to the docs this should be enough but I keep getting the error `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.`

Comment: Is there a tutorial kind of thing we could take a look at? I am also stuck with the same problem.